# How big does an atom need to be to have dispersion forces be greater than other intermolecular forces?

Tags: organic-chemistry, intermolecular-forces

I know as an atom gets bigger the dispersion forces grow with it. But how big does an atom, e.g methanoic acid, to have dispersion forces that outrank dipole-dipole forces?

Comment: Methanoic acid is not an atom.

Comment: How big should a man be in order to be more effective in sumo wrestling than in karate? Some men certainly are big enough, and some certainly aren't, and you won't be able to pinpoint the exact border. Same thing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean molecules, not atoms. Regardless let's just say you meant molecule and by intermolecular you're really just focusing on Dipole, the answer is- youre comparing apples to oranges.  But you don't look at 1 molecule interacting with another rather a whole bunch of molecules interacting simultaneously.  At some moment when electrons are gravitating toward 1 atom in a molecule and another molecule nearby has dipolarization and the relative distance can cause bonds to break and realign on another molecule.  But I think what you mean is, what kind of atoms in a molecule would be impacted by dispersion force the most? And that's large molecules and also large atoms because large atoms like iodine, can have an induced dipole from a atoms its not bonded to much easier than a tiny atom.  How big? There really isn't any way to answer that question.